# Slick game Error The method add State(Game State) in the type StateBasedGame is not applicable for the arguments (Play)

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

The method `addState(GameState)` in the type `StateBasedGame` is not applicable for the arguments (Play)

I am having the above error for the following code I can't seem to find anything that will help me solve this and I am still a beginner to Java. I am trying to make a pong game once I am done with setup...

```
package pong;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
public class pongmain extends StateBasedGame{

    public pongmain(String gamename) {
        super(gamename);
        this.addState(new Play(play));
    }

    public static final String gamename = "Pong";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: also in error log it says: Description Resource Path Location Type
play cannot be resolved to a variable pongmain.java /GAME001/src/pong line 8 Java Problem

Comment: I am a damn idiot I forgot to add 
    public static final int play = 1; Lets hope that works